# How do I access to the value enclosed inside [[]] (double large bracket) from my promise result?

Tags: javascript, rest, promise, github-api

I am working on the Github OAuth Authentication button. The button when clicked will get access token from my Github Account to get me verified for my application.

To get my "access token" I have to send a request using a custom middleware and a custom "code", the GitHub will exchange this code and provide me the "access token"(according to the Github API).

**What is working??**

I am able to get the code and put this code in my "fetch", and able to get the access token in the object as well.

My code for fetching the token :

```
fetch(
    `https://gitfund-oauth.herokuapp.com/authenticate/${CODE}`
  ).then((response) => console.log(response.json()))
```

**What is the issue?**

I am getting a response, where the access token is enclosed inside the double large bracket, so how do I get that? 
I am getting a response as:

[image]

How do I get the token from the object? I tried to do the `response.json().PromiseValue`, but it did not work.
If anybody can explain what is the double large bracket and how can I access the value, and what notation like this means in the promise chain.


Any help would mean a lot.
Thank You

Comment: To be honest reading any fetch() documentation would answer this for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). You will need to chain another `.then()` on it to get back the resolved promise value like:

```
fetch(`https://gitfund-oauth.herokuapp.com/authenticate/${CODE}`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

**Demo:**

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

For more info: [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: But the demo here is working fine and returning an object, right?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know, what [[]] means? How is it different from retrieving data from regular objects?

Comment: It worked, I was doing something very silly. I did not remove my `console.log` before chaining the data parameter, that's why I was getting undefined

Comment: [[]] is just a Promise object. You can read more about it in details here: [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul The *[[…]]* notation is used for representing the promise internals by the console/debugger. They are not normal properties accessible from JS.

Answer (score 2):

The response.json() is a promise too. So you should use the same then/catch promise OR use the await operator.

For example:

```
fetch(`https://gitfund-oauth.herokuapp.com/authenticate/${CODE}`)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns another promise, So we have to chain it like this :

```
 fetch(`https://gitfund-oauth.herokuapp.com/authenticate/${CODE}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data.token))
}
```

Comment: Why have you posted this answer when other answers have already mentioned the same thing?